# The type OWLOntologyWalkerVisitor is not generic: Error using OWL API in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, owl-api

I have a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse 3.4 , Jsf 1.2, java 1.7, tomcat 7 and owl api 4.0. I am using example code from [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/master/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Examples.java) in a backing bean of java. This code runs smooth in Java Application but generates error while used in JSF project and run on tomcat 7 server.

The code snippet is as follows:-

```
OWLOntologyWalkerVisitor<Object> visitor = new OWLOntologyWalkerVisitor<Object>(
            walker) {
            @Override
            public Object visit(OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom desc) {
            // Print out the restriction
            System.out.println(desc);
            // Print out the axiom where the restriction is used
            System.out.println(" " + getCurrentAxiom());
            System.out.println();
            // We don't need to return anything here.
            return null;
            }
            };
            // Now ask the walker to walk over the ontology structure using our
            // visitor instance.
            walker.walkStructure(visitor);
```

while the error it generates is:-

```
 The type OWLOntologyWalkerVisitor is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments<Object>
```

Any clue why is this happening?

Comment: The javadoc says it's generic, and the examples in the documentation use it with a type parameter.  You may need to describe your configuration a bit more in order to get a diagnosis.  Also, I've added the [tag:java] tag to this question;  It's generally a good idea to tag with the primary language that your question involves, as it gets the right people looking at it, and it helps with automatic syntax highlighting.  Similarly, I added [tag:owlapi] and removed [tag:api] and [tag:owl].  Be sure to read the tag descriptions when you're writing your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code you have linked is for owlapi 3.5 (master branch). The correct example is in the version4 branch - apologies, probably a few documentation links are stale.

Edit: version 4 Examples.java is here:
https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java

https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation

Comment: i had an idea that the problem is due to version mix. but the link to owl 4 api example brings about 404 error. can u refer link to correct example?